# Общедоступный профиль продавца и юр.лицо в Play Console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Вопрос по поводу платежного профиля в Play Console. Когда регистрируемся в Google Play и вводим данные о платежном профиле то там есть общедоступный профиль продавца, куда мы вводим название юр.лица (в моем случае ИП). У меня вопрос про это:

1. Для чего конкретно нужна эта информация?
2. Это означает что без ИП я не смогу продавать товары и подписки в приложении?
3. Мое ИП зарегистрировано в Казахстане, там есть свой налог как и в разных странах для ИП есть их налоги, вопрос - допустим человек купил подписку у меня, Google забрал комиссию, заплатил налог стране, в которой произведена покупка. Когда сумма мне поступила на счет, я с нее еще должен заплатить налог своему государству?

Answer (score 0):

Читал что вообще гугл больше смотрит на счёт и куда переводить деньги, в каком формате будете отчитываться по налогам это не его проблема.
Посмотрите на стартовой странице регистрации гугл консоли - там есть подсказка какой тип выбрать. Ещё насколько знаю под ИП можно работать с индивидуальным типом аккаунта.
И без ИП вы также сможете продавать подписки и т д, главное счёт указать